# What would be some implications of Schanuel's conjecture being proven wrong?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory, transcendence-degree

Schanuel's conjecture is an important conjecture in transcendental number theory, which is:

Given any $n$ complex numbers $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n$ that are linearly independent over the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$, the field extension $\Bbb Q(z_1, ... z_n, e^{z_1}, ..., e^{z_n})$ has transcendence degree at least $n$ over $\Bbb Q$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) lists some consequences of this being true. It would strengthen both the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem and Baker's theorem by showing that linearly independent logarithms of algebraic numbers are also algebraically independent, which would in turn make it easy to settle the transcendence of $\pi+e$, $e^e$, and so on, as well as that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent.

**My question**: what would be some of the results if this conjecture were instead false? How would that change transcendental number theory?

Comment: There'd be a lot more identities to find!

Comment: I do not know whether it were easy to show the transcendence assuming the truth of the conjecture, but actually the consequence would be that many such numbers could be shown to be transcendental. However, those numbers could also be transcendental even if Schnauel's conjecture would be false. All what would have happened is that this particular try to extend the transcendental-number-theory would have failed.